# How to introduce indexing to sqlite query in android?

Tags: sqlite, indexing, android-sqlite

In my android application, I use `Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);` to query data from a local sqlite database, and one of the `query` string looks like the following:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM table t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1 FROM table t2
  WHERE t2.start_time = t1.start_time AND t2.stop_time > t1.stop_time
)
```

however, the issue is that the query gets very slow when the database gets huge. Trying to look into introducing `indexing` to speed up the query, but so far, not been very successful, therefore, would be great to have some help here, as it's also hard to find examples for this for android applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a composite index for the columns `start_time` and `stop_time`:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_name ON table_name(start_time, stop_time);
```

You can read in [The SQLite Query Optimizer Overview](https://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html):

> The ON and USING clauses of an inner join are converted into
> additional terms of the WHERE clause prior to WHERE clause analysis
> ...

and:

> If an index is created using a statement like this:
>
> ```
> CREATE INDEX idx_ex1 ON ex1(a,b,c,d,e,...,y,z);
> ```
>
> Then the index might be used if the initial columns of the index
> (columns a, b, and so forth) appear in WHERE clause terms. The initial
> columns of the index must be used with the = or IN or IS operators.
> **The right-most column that is used can employ inequalities.**

You may have to uninstall the app from the device so that the db is deleted and rerun to recreate it, or increase the version number of the db so that you can create the index in the `onUpgrade()` method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, just another quick question, after added the creation of the composite index, does the query string remain the same?

Comment: @user3442437 the query remains the same. It is up to the query planner to use the index.

Comment: I got another question, are there other things than indexing that I can do to speed the query up even more?

Comment: @user3442437 of course there are. You can try different methods to obtain the same results and compare the speed. SQLite also supports window functions since version 3.25.0, that could be used instead of EXISTS and provide better performance but unfortunately Android up until API level 29, uses SQLite version 3.22.0

Comment: what would be the faster way to do the following query?

SELECT * FROM t 
    WHERE time >=  yesterday 
    AND time <= now 
    AND user = test

Comment: @user3442437 it depends on the column time. If it contains only a date and not time, it could be written as  SELECT * FROM t WHERE (time = yesterday OR time = today) AND user = test and maybe indexes could be used. If time is a timestamp then it is fine as it is but I'm not sure that indexes could be used.

Comment: its timestamp and indexing helped, however, it still costs 9.284 sec to get a result of 388 items from a query from a table with a size of 1066. is this normal? or i must have done something wrong here

Comment: @user3442437 no it is not normal. This is a small dataset.

Comment: the slowness issue comes from converting the cursor to a list! thank you for your answers, they helped a lot!